# Azure blob storage streaming performance issue

Tags: azure, performance, stream, azure-blob-storage, filestream

My application till this day was working with local zip files,
meaning I was using a direct return `new FileStream()`
in the application and the local zip file that was located on the SDD/Network drive path (zip files can be hundreds of GB).

I configured the application to work with Azure Blob Storage, meaning each FileStream that was returned in now return as the Azure Blob SDK method:

```
GetBlobStreamAsync(ContainerName, BlobName).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
```

I uploaded some zip files to a container in the blob storage and set the connection string in the application to work with that storage account.

The application was deployed and running on a virtual windows machine located in the same region of the Azure Storage Blob.

Note: This is a private cloud network.

When the app is streaming the zip file on Azure blob storage it seems that the performance has decreased by at least 8-9 times (problematic with hundreds of GB).

Speed comparison is between local C: drive on the same windows virtual machine that the application is running on an Azure Storage account which is located in the same region.

Note: NW Bandwidth - is 50 GB on the VM on azure

Solutions that I tried:

1. Azure blob Premium Performance storage - **Didn’t** improve performance
2. .Net Core - advantage of performance enhancements (we work with .Net framework so this is irrelevant).
3. Network File System (NFS) 3.0 performance considerations in Azure Blob storage - (**Does not** work with private cloud).
4. Hot, Cool, and Archive access tiers for blob data - The default is Hot so we already tried this scenario with **no improvements**.

Solutions I want to try:

1. Azure Files Share Storage as a cache solution
2. .Net Framework configuration -  lists several quick configuration settings that you can use to make significant performance improvements

Question:

Does anyone have any suggestions on how can I optimize the streaming in front of the Azure Storage Blob?

Comment: When you say "the performance has decreased by at least 8-9 times" you compare the speed to your network drive to Azure Storage? Where is your network drive located and where is your Azure Storage account placed? I assume you connect over public Internet and not over a private connection (e.g. ExpressRoute)?

Comment: Are the Azure VM your code is running on and the storage account in the same Azure VNet?

Comment: The VM & the Blob storage account are in the same regions. For now, we set them as public (was private but we wanted to check if this is the issue and seems not), same Resource group, Subscription.

Comment: 1. Was your code always synchronous? Why is it synchronous? 2. What's the VM SKU? 3. What's the storage SDK configuration/options? 4. Could you share your code that deals with streaming the blob?

Comment: 1. Yes, the new FileStream() is a legacy synchronous code and I didn't want to break it, I just added another case of cloud which is returning BlobStreamAsync.GetResult()   
 
2. Windows VM, Standard D16s v3 (16 vcpus, 64 GiB memory)
3. Not sure what you mean by  SDK configuration/options 
4. Not really, but it uses the synchronous code like this
using (Stream stream = GetBlobStreamAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()) The function of GetBlobStreamAsync is just using the SDK of Azure

 return await BlobClient .OpenReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

Answer (score 1):

Azure Files (share) or Storage Blob services are likely not the right services to be utilized for this scenario. There are two possible paths:

1. Break a single file into multiple files and leverage Storage Blob service that handles throughput better than Azure Files. Azure Files performs better with small(er) files which are typical to user documents (PDFs, Word, Excel, etc.)
2. Switch over to a more dedicated service that is designed specifically for large-size data transfer if breaking up a single file into multiple blobs is not an option.

The recommendation for each option will highly depend on the implementation details, requirements and constraints of the system.